# Login with email-id and password

Tags: android

I want to create a login application which will asks email-id and password from the user. Then this email-id and password will be checked on the email-provider server like google, or yahoo.

How can I do this?
For this, I think i need to send the Request to email-provider server with email-id and password and get back the response from the email-provider server. So how can I send a request and get a response from the URL? Is there any specific format for sending request and getting response from the server??

Please help me to achieve the task.

Thanks
Deepak Kumar

Comment: Go to your old questions and tick one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use client/server mechanism. Afetr u get the response u can parse it either using SAX-Parser or SOAP client